# Highchart Tooltip showing the same values no matter where you click

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am implemented the formatter function for my tooltip in the highchart component of my angular 4 application. I am getting the tooltip well formatted with the x and y values but unfortunately it doesn't seem like it is looping through the series. It is constantly showing the same tooltip no matter where you hover your mouse on the highchart. Please find the screenshot and code below. I have written the formatting for tooltip in formatter: function() under tooltip section of the highchart .Am i missing something

Tooltip

[image]

Boxplot

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ShortNumberFormatPipe } from '@wtw/toolkit';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-box-plot-chart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
        chart{
              display: block;
              width: 100% !important;
              padding:0;
        }
    `]
})

//, width: number
export class BoxPlotChartComponent implements OnInit {
    static chart(shortNumberFormatPipe: ShortNumberFormatPipe, translate: TranslateService, moduleName: string, height: number, graphLegendTitle: string) {
        return {
            chart: {
                type: 'boxplot',
                reflow: true,
                height: height
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        allowHTML: true,
                        enabled: true,
                        margin: 25,
                        itemMarginTop: 0,
                        symbolRadius: 0,
                        symbolHeight: 20,
                        symbolWidth: 20,
                        useHTML: true,
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                           title: {
                            text: '',
                         }
                    },
                    chart: {
                        events: null
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {

                lineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                minorTickLength: 0,
                tickLength: 0
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }, plotLines: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,

                formatter: function() {
                    let isMillionNumber: boolean = false;
                    const row = function(label, value) {
                        const key = 'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.';

                        return '<tr><td style="font-size:10px;">' + translate.instant(key + label) + ': </td>'
                            + '<td style="font-size:10px;"><b>' + value + '</b></td></tr>';
                    };

                    const transformNumber = function(value) {
                        isMillionNumber = validateMillionNumber(value);
                        if (isMillionNumber || moduleName === 'eva')
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 2);
                        else
                            return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 0);
                    };

                    const table = function(format, point) {
                        let txt = '<strong style="font-size:12px;color:' + point.color + '">' + point.name + '</strong><br><br>';
                        txt += '<table>';
                        if (moduleName === 'npv') {
                            txt += row('HIGH', format(point.high));
                            txt += row('Q3', format(point.q3));
                            txt += row('MEDIAN', format(point.median));
                            txt += row('Q1', format(point.q1));
                            txt += row('LOW', format(point.low));
                        } else if (moduleName === 'eva') {
                            txt += row('HIGH', format(point.high) + '%');
                            txt += row('Q3', format(point.q3) + '%');
                            txt += row('MEDIAN', format(point.median) + '%');
                            txt += row('Q1', format(point.q1) + '%');
                            txt += row('LOW', format(point.low) + '%');
                        }
                        txt += '</table>';
                        return txt;
                    };

                    let point = this.points[0].point;

                    return table(transformNumber, point);

                    function validateMillionNumber(millionNumber: number) {
                        return millionNumber >= 1000000;
                    }

                },
            },
            series: []
        };
    }

    public options: any;
    chart: any;
    @Input() public series: any;
    @Input() public moduleName: string = '';
    @Input() public height: number = 400;

    private shortNumberFormatPipe = new ShortNumberFormatPipe();

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let graphLegendTitle: string = this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.GRAPH_LEGEND_TITLE');
        this.options = BoxPlotChartComponent.chart(this.shortNumberFormatPipe, this._translate, this.moduleName, this.height, graphLegendTitle);
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }


    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;
        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;
        this._redrawLogic(this.series);
        this.chart.redraw();
    }

    private _redrawLogic(series: any) {
        let seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        for (let i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
        }

        series.map(s => {
            if (s !== null) {
                this.chart.addSeries(s);
            }
        });

        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-legend-item path');
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
            elements[i].setAttribute('stroke-height', '20');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i believe it would be always showing one series because of this line but how do i get the selected series let point = this.points[0].point;

Comment: Can you show `data.series.currentValue` ? Maybe your data is like 1.7102M etc. and simply your formatter rounds values? You can test is by setting higher number in: `return shortNumberFormatPipe.transform(value, 2);` (e.g. 6?)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you meant but currently the tool tip shows up when you hover your mouse anywhere on the high chart. I have set the series color and name as well. Also the window shows up next the top series only which i think is series 1 since I have let point = this.points[0].point.

Comment: Ok, could you recreate issue in jsfiddle? Maybe you simply need to disable `shared = false` and use `this.point.point` instead of `this.points[0].point` ?

Comment: Just to let you know the issue got fixed partly with your solution. shared = false and  let point = this.point